# How to determine what is killing my Screen?

Tags: screen, kill

I've got a test suite running in a detached Screen that appears to be getting killed, and I'm not sure why (or how). I checked the logs of my software, and there's no indication of a problem. The test logs stop at 14:09:50 on Mar 30, but the syslog doesn't report a shutdown until 14:12:34, so the gap of ~2 minutes is suspicious (it's very unlikely for the test to be quiet for longer than few seconds at most), and indicates to me that whatever triggered the shutdown probably started closer to 14:09:50.

Here's a snippet of the syslog:

```
Mar 30 14:10:30 foo-system NetworkManager[774]: <info>  [1553980230.8267]   server identifier 10.201.X.X
Mar 30 14:10:30 foo-system NetworkManager[774]: <info>  [1553980230.8267]   lease time 1800
Mar 30 14:10:30 foo-system NetworkManager[774]: <info>  [1553980230.8267]   nameserver '10.201.X.X'
Mar 30 14:10:30 foo-syMar 30 14:12:34 foo-system systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Mar 30 14:12:34 foo-system systemd[14623]: Reached target Shutdown.
Mar 30 14:12:34 foo-system systemd[14623]: Starting Exit the Session...
Mar 30 14:12:34 foo-system systemd[14623]: Stopped target Default.
Mar 30 14:12:34 foo-system systemd[14623]: Stopped target Basic System.
Mar 30 14:12:34 foo-system systemd[14623]: Stopped target Timers.
Mar 30 14:12:34 foo-system systemd[14623]: Stopped target Sockets.
Mar 30 14:12:34 foo-system systemd[14623]: Stopped target Paths.
Mar 30 14:12:34 foo-system systemd[14623]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 21470 (kill).
Mar 30 14:12:34 foo-system systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.
Mar 30 14:12:34 foo-system systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of userbar.
```

What I find interesting is the log itself looks to be interrupted at 14:10, without even finishing its line, in the middle of a routine NetworkManager report (which happens roughly every 12 minutes, and should have had a few more lines to go) with a lot of Stop messaging. I've dug enough to determine that this wasn't a system shutdown/reboot event (and boot logs confirm the system has been up since Feb 2018, over a year ago). I have no idea what could be triggering this shutdown, but I need it to stop.

UID 1000 is the user that the test runs under, codename 'userbar'.

The test runs under a detached Screen instance to allow its continued execution, and this was a design choice over backgrounding to allow reporting to connect to the process and check on its health.

*Background:*
This is on an Ubuntu VM running a test 24/7. It has been up for over a year, without problems that weren't limited to the test suite itself (or user error related to the same). That is, the OS or its systems was never a problem. It wasn't until last month, roughly it's 1 year anniversary (coincidentally?), that the test has been getting shutdown without any warning. It's important to note the system hasn't been rebooted, applied any updates, or installed any software in that time (and certainly not in the last 1-2 months).

The first time the test went down, I restarted it without investigating the cause. I just assumed the test itself fell over, and it was a fluke occurrence related to some network issues we were having around the same time. The test itself has had no significant changes for about two months. It had been running for about a week when it fell over again (a couple days ago). This time, I dug into the test suite's logs. But there're no critical errors reported, it just stopped abruptly.

The syslog appeared to have the most telling information, but this is unclear to me. Any ideas what could be the problem, or where I need to look to find out more?